# How to animate one grid item into full screen width in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, gridview, android-jetpack-compose, android-animation

What I need:

To have a grid layout where each button can animate into big image to cover full screen width, then animate back into place.

I know how to use AnimatedContent and LazyVerticalGrid. But how to make the button
increase in size and expand to the full screen width?

[image: design]